# How did the prophets behave in the death of disbelievers (amongst loved ones)?

Tags: non-muslim, death

when a muslim dies we can pray for him , (for example his/her sins to be forgiven). But in case of a non muslim we cannot do anything or even express sorrow this is what I heard. I want to know, how did the prophets behave when their loved ones in disbelievers died? How did they express their grief or mourn?

Answer (score 1):

Before the Surah Al-Munafiqoon (63) verse 7, prophet SAW pray for deliverers, so Allah send down this ayah. After that Prophet SAW never pray for deliverers.

[Verse 63:7](https://quran.com/63/7)

> It is all the same for them whether you ask forgiveness for them or do
>   not ask forgiveness for them; never will Allah forgive them. Indeed,
>   Allah does not guide the defiantly disobedient people.

[Verse (9:80)](http://corpus.quran.com/translation.jsp?chapter=9&verse=80)

> Ask forgiveness for them, [O Muhammad], or do not ask forgiveness for
>   them. If you should ask forgiveness for them seventy times - never
>   will Allah forgive them. That is because they disbelieved in Allah and
>   His Messenger, and Allah does not guide the defiantly disobedient
>   people.

Here 70 time is an example, means, never matter how many times you will ask forgiveness for them, Allah will not forgive them.

As a human being, Muslims are the best, we can join them and share their pain, it is proved by Hadith.